# Special characters in WordPress UTF-8

Tags: database, characters, htmlspecialchars-decode

I have a problem regarding special characters that are appearing messed up on the front-end .
mainly the get converted to question marks, or something like �?)

Example - Frédèric becomes Fr�d�ric.

some facts that made me puzzled:

- This WP install is on LOCAL machine, and shares the server with at
  least 40  other installs - none of which have this problem.
- This WP install shares also the same DB as the others .
- My wp-config file has the collate and charset defined.
- The DB seems fine , because when I am viewing the post in the EDITOR (back end) - all is correct , the problem is only on the FRONT end .

  - The DB seems fine (2) , opening the post in phpMyAdmin and checking the direct value - all characters are fine .
- This problem is NOT a browser/os encoding , it was checked in 4
  different machines, 3 OS, and 9 browsers..

I have tried all the solutions which I know from past experience, which include :

- checking the wp-config (it is ok, utf-8 defined, collate ok)
- Checking the DB - all UTF-8
- checking my header `(<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>`) - that renders
  correctly as utf-8 with valid markup.
- Open all theme files in my editor, convert encoding to UTF-8 without
  bom and save.

Did i missed something ? Any Ideas ??

Comment: And your files are written/saved in UTF-8 (Themes, Plugins)?

Comment: yep - I already wrote it in the question itself. UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: You wrote "Theme", not plugins. Sure you have deactivated all plugins?

Comment: no. I did not deactivated any plugins, because none are installed (well, maybe askimet or hello dolly - but not activated)

Comment: The only situation where I stepped into something similiar, was with Google Geocoding results as they are _not defined_. Help was to convert everything to utf-8 on pre_save hook.

Comment: Why the tag `htmlspecialchars-decode`? Does the problem happen with TwentyEleven too?

Comment: @ Kaiser - thanks , i DO have a google.maps related functions that I wrote - .. I will look into it -  although NON of them is actually evoked.  @toscho - the tag is because it MIGHT be related to a problem in html special characters decoding and encoding. and yes , it happens with TwentyEleven too.

Comment: UPDATE - still have no idea what is the problem .. But I used php´s mb_convert_encoding (). it is not ideal of course , and I would still like to know WHY it happened in order to avoid future problems, so if anyone has an idea/solution - please post.

Comment: Hi @Obmerkronen, sounds fascinating. Here's what I would try if you haven't already: Run a fresh install of WordPress on a new DB and verify that UTF-8 chars work. If so, change wp-config.php to use the DB of your, we'll call it "corrupt", install. If the clean install works on its own DB and doesn't work on the "corrupt" DB, you know it's your DB. If the clean install works with both, you know it's the files in the "corrupt" install. If the fresh install doesn't work, it's most likely a PHP or MySQL setting (which is possible even if other old installs are working). Let me know what happens!

Comment: @ Matthew Boynes - thanks for your interest ! I actually made this check already when I was struggling with the problem - on a clean install It still had the same pathology - even without changing nothing and no extra functions (but the ones I wrote - which are totally unrelated and harmless...Since then I have moved to another project , But as soon as I can, I will try to understand why it happened !

Comment: It may be your server.  DO you have an .htaccess file for the domain or folder in which WordPress is installed?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Do you have `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in your `<head>` tag? A user [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/utf-8-encoding-problem) fixed a similar problem with character encoding by adding this.

There are actually [many Google results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=utf-8%20character%20encoding%20in%20wordpress&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=4bd463be09dc681c&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4bd463be09dc681c&ion=1&biw=1920&bih=955) that come up searching for `utf-8 character encoding in wordpress`.

Also, does pasting the text into the HTML view of the editor and saving it make any difference?

---

**Below is not such a good idea as @toscho explained in comments.**

I am not sure if this is the best method to fix the problem but [this](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480) worked for one of my clients' websites.

Find these two lines in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

And comment them out like so:

```
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: Now you risk to get mixed saved encodings. Not a good idea.

Comment: @toscho Correct, I'm poking around the web for a better solution and will update my answer soon.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8" />

Adding this worked form me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using htmlentities() to escape your output by any chance? If so you need to define 'UTF-8' as the third parameter.